# Request Header value and then set database connection string accordingly for multitenancy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a requirement to get a header value and then set connection string according to the tenant.

my appsettings.json

```
 "TenantSettings": {
  "Defaults": {
"DBProvider": "mssql",
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial 
Catalog=sharedTenantDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
},
   "Tenants": [
    {
  "Name": "alpha",
  "TID": "alpha",
  "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial 
 Catalog=alphaTenantDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
},
{
  "Name": "beta",
  "TID": "beta",
  "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial 
 Catalog=betaTenantDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
},
{
  "Name": "charlie",
  "TID": "charlie"
},
{
  "Name": "java",
  "TID": "java"
  }
]
 }
```

my startup.cs

```
 namespace Eigen.UE.WebUI.Razor
 {
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = InitConfiguration(env);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDatabase()
            .AddServices();
        
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/EigenLog-{Date}.txt",outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:o}][{Level:u3}][{Message}]{Newline}{Exception}{NewLine}");
        //loggerFactory.AddFile()


        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();

            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

   
    }

    private IConfiguration InitConfiguration(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // Config the app to read values from appsettings base on current environment value.
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
        //
        // Map AppSettings section in appsettings.json file value to AppSetting model
        configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>(options => options.BindNonPublicProperties = true);
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

}

My ServicecollectionExtensions.cs

```
 namespace Eigen.UE.WebUI.Razor.Extensions
 {
 public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Add needed instances for database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddDatabase(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Configure DbContext with Scoped lifetime   
        
        services.AddDbContext<DemoContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(AppSettings.ConnectionString,
                    sqlOptions => sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(120));
                //options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
            }
        );

        services.AddScoped<Func<DemoContext>>((provider) => () => provider.GetService<DemoContext>());
        services.AddScoped<DbFactory>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

        return services;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add instances of in-use services
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddScoped<IWorkService, WorkService>();
         services.AddScoped<IUserInfoService, UserInfoService>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

}

Now this is where I set the connection string.

`services.AddDbContext<DemoContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(AppSettings.ConnectionString, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(120)); //options.UseLazyLoadingProxies(); } );`

Now Where should I get the request header and set the  connectionstring accordingly?
In appsettings.json I have the headervalue and connection string respectively
I understand I should use the httpcontext to access the header value, but where will I insert the line of that code?

Comment: Have you tried a Middleware solution? It gets called during every HTTP request and you have access to the HttpContext and could set your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to inject HttpContextAccessor into dbcontext and override the OnConfiguring method to get the related information in requestheader:

in Dbcontext:

```
public class xxContext : DbContext
    {

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;


        public xxContext (DbContextOptions<CheckPointDemoxxContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IConfiguration configuration)
            : base(options)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public DbSet<xx> xx { get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            ...          
            
        }
        public string Connectstring ()
        {
            var conname = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["SomeConname"].ToString();
            string constr;
            if (conname != "")
            {
                 constr = _configuration.GetConnectionString(conname);
            }
            else
            {
                constr = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeContext");
            }
            
            return constr;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Connectstring());
        }


    }
```

in startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddDbContext<CheckPointDemoContext>();
```

in appsetting.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SomeContext-4c252eaa-1dce-4260-b86a-f3c827a06f6d;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "AnotherContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AnotherContext-9c23de7b-830e-4494-9a87-73618f526830;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: I shall check this.